# Updated list does not change on UI when PropertyChanged is called in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a bindable `StackLayout` bound to a `List` in the `ViewModel`. When a button is pressed I am adding an element to the list and then invoking `PropertyChanged` with the name of the list.

I don't understand why the UI does not get updated in this case. I know that I should use an `ObservableCollection`, and I know how to do it, but I am curious about why the UI does not change if I am invoking `PropertyChanged` myself.

This is the ViewModel and Model class:

```
    public class Element
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public List<Element> Elements { get; set; }
        public ICommand AddElementCommand { get; private set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            AddElementCommand = new Command(AddElement);

            Elements = new List<Element>();
            Elements.Add(new Element { Value = "test1" });
        }

        void AddElement()
        {
            Elements.Add(new Element { Value = "testAgain" });
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Elements"));
        }
    }
```

And this is the view:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TestList.MainPage"
             x:Name="page">
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Elements"
                       FontSize="Large"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding AddElementCommand}"
                    Text="+" FontSize="Title"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                      <Entry Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Try to use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`

Comment: @cahyo As I said in the text, I know that I can use an  `ObservableCollection`. I am asking why this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we check the source code of **ObservableCollection** , we will see that it had implemented **INotifyCollectionChanged** and **INotifyPropertyChanged** in default while **List** didn't .

```
public class ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

```
public class List<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, ICollection, IList
```

If a list will contain the same items for their whole lifetime, but the individual objects within that list will change, then it's enough for just the objects to raise change notifications (typically through **INotifyPropertyChanged**) and **List** is sufficient. But if the list will contain different objects from time to time, or if the order changes, then you should use **ObservableCollection**.

That is why we always suggest users to choose **ObservableCollection** instead of **List** .

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this does not answer the question, as you're still using an  `ObservableCollection `, and I know that I can do it this way. I am asking why it does not work just by using a  `List` and  `PropertyChanged ` like I did. I would expect that if I notify that the  ` List` property has changed, then it would be updated in the UI, but it didn't happen, and I am looking for the reason.

Comment: I have just tried your updated answer, and it still does not work, neither on iOS or Android

Comment: You could share the sample so that I can test it on my side directly .

Comment: Sure, that's fine by me, but do you have any suggestions about how do I send it to you?

Comment: You could upload it to github . By the way , did you check my code ? It works fine as you can see in screenshot .

Comment: https://gitlab.com/papafe/testnotify -- here you can find the code.
And yes, I have copied the code you posted in my project and it doesn't update the list. In the MainViewModel file in my project I've commented out my own code and put yours. Maybe we're using two different versions of Xamarin.Forms that deal differently with this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219161/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-papafe).

Comment: I have accepted this as an answer. For whoever reads, please note that the previous comments are related to the previous versions of the answer, that was edited twice